# How to compare a list of processes i get from a .csv file with the processes currently running on the machine? In Powershell

Tags: powershell

This is what i have so far:

```
#Laufende Dienste

$Service = Get-Service | where{$_.Status -eq "Running"} 

foreach($x in $Service){
    Write-Host $x.ServiceName

}    

#Standard Dienste importieren

$csvfile = Import-CSV -Path "K:\Example\Example.csv"
Foreach ($x in $csvfile) {
    Write-Host $x.Name
}

#Vergleichen

Compare-Object -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent $csvfil $ServiceName
```

The bottom part that should compare the two lists of processes doesnt seem to work tho

Comment: Each object list should belong to one of the parameters: `Compare-Object -IncludeEqual $csvfil -ExcludeDifferent $ServiceName`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare the property servicename retrieved by get-service with the property name of the objects from the csv file you can do:

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject (get-service).servicename -DifferenceObject (import-csv [path]).name -ExcludeDifferent -IncludeEqual
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$servicesList1 = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name 
$servicesList1 | Out-File 'S:\temp1';

Stop-Service -Name 'AppleChargerSrv'

$servicesListOld = Get-Content 'S:\temp1'
$servicesListNow = Get-Service | Where-Object {$_.Status -eq "Running"} | Select -ExpandProperty Name
$servicesListDiff = Compare-Object  -ReferenceObject $servicesListOld -DifferenceObject $servicesListNow
```

---

```
InputObject     SideIndicator
-----------     -------------
AppleChargerSrv <=
```